# Script/program language to use for opening a collection of text files and checking content

Tags: file, powershell, comparison

Could anybody recommend a programming language which would be best to use for opening up a list of text files (config files) in one folder and then comparing the content of the file with another file in a different location? I would want to do a line by line compare. Could you do this kind of thing with Powershell or using a Batch file?

Please dont recommend comparison software such as WinMerge or BeyondCompare as I want to automate this process i.e. not manually open up two files and compare them.

Thanks for any advice you can give me :-).

Comment: How big are the files and how many are there?

Comment: The language is irrelevant. Relevant is how you process the files (i.e. the algorithm you implement in whatever language).

Comment: The files are web.config files and are less than 100Kbytes in size. There will be about 40 files that need comparing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this can be done in `PowerShell` using `Get-Content` and `Compare-Objet` Cmdlets.

```
$A = Get-Content c:\x.txt
$B = Get-Content c:\y.txt
Compare-Object A$ B$
```

This will return a object that look similar to below. It indicates differences that are in one file and not in the other line by line. ([Ref](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156812.aspx))

```
InputObject                             SideIndicator
-----------                             -------------
Something ......                        =>
Something else                          <=
```